# CheckBoxList '.Selected' is returning false in every situation

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I am trying to grab multiple values from a checkboxlist and add them to a list, But checked values are always false even though the list contains appropriate count value.

code to populate:

```
Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
HelpingOthersEntities helpData = new HelpingOthersEntities();
List<LookupStoreLocationsByUserName> theDataSet = helpData.LookupStoreLocationsByUserName(userGuid).ToList<LookupStoreLocationsByUserName>();
locCkBox.DataSource = theDataSet;
locCkBox.DataTextField = "slAddress";
locCkBox.DataValueField = "storeLocationID";
locCkBox.DataBind();
```

code for adding to list:

```
List<int> locList = new List<int>();

for (int x = 0; x < locCkBox.Items.Count; x++){
   if(locCkBox.Items[x].Selected){
        locList.Add(int.Parse(locCkBox.Items[x].Value));
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that I cannot get into `items.selected`
 my value is always false.

I have tried populating the checkboxes from postback but i get the same result. My list gives me the appropriate `.Count` amount of values, but `items.selected` = false?

I have tried a foreach loop to add to list as well but I get the same results over and over. Am i missing an event or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess here and say that your code that does the population stuff is being called in the pageload event, so you have something like the following.

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
    HelpingOthersEntities helpData = new HelpingOthersEntities();
    List<LookupStoreLocationsByUserName> theDataSet = helpData.LookupStoreLocationsByUserName(userGuid).ToList<LookupStoreLocationsByUserName>();
    locCkBox.DataSource = theDataSet;
    locCkBox.DataTextField = "slAddress";
    locCkBox.DataValueField = "storeLocationID";
    locCkBox.DataBind();
}
```

If that's the case then your effectively writing over the postback data on each request. To sort this out you need to only perform the databinding when its not a postback, so you need to change the above code to

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        HelpingOthersEntities helpData = new HelpingOthersEntities();
        List<LookupStoreLocationsByUserName> theDataSet = helpData.LookupStoreLocationsByUserName(userGuid).ToList<LookupStoreLocationsByUserName>();
        locCkBox.DataSource = theDataSet;
        locCkBox.DataTextField = "slAddress";
        locCkBox.DataValueField = "storeLocationID";
        locCkBox.DataBind();
    }
}
```

You should then be able to test the Selected property of the items. I'd also probably change the code your using to test for the selected to something like

```
List<int> locList = new List<int>();
foreach(var item in locCkBox.Items)
{
  if(item.Selected)
  {
    locList.Add(int.Parse(item.Value));
  }
}
```

or if your on a .NET version with LINQ available

```
List<int> locList = new List<int>();
(from item in locCkBox.Items where item.Selected == true select item).ForEach(i => locList.Add(i.Value));
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure while binding the `checkboxlist` in page load you have set this check.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
...bind your data
}
```

This should do the trick.